# Query Entity Framework using C# and Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

First of all I am new to both C# and EF.

I have created a number of entities with the the Model designer in VS 2015 CE and set the relationships.

I would like to query the entities to return all the customers for a specific Contract (e.g. Contract_ID = 1), along with related properties from the CustomerLocker and ContractCustomer entities (For the CustomerLocker Entity if they are present, or null if they are not).  I also have the LockerNumber value from the Contract entity (e.g. 100).

I would be grateful if someone can help with the LINQ query required to select the properties I require.  I would prefer to be able to use navigation properties if possible.

So far I am able to select the customers but not able to select properties from the CustomerLocker entity.

```
    var myCustomers = (from cc in context.ContractCustomers
    where cc.Contract_ID.Equals(contractID)
    select new
    {
    Licencee = cc.IsLicencee,
    Added = cc.AddedDate,
    Firstname = cc.Customer.FirstName,
    Lastname =  cc.Customer.LastName,
    DOB = cc.Customer.DateOfBirth,
    Postcode = cc.Customer.PostCode,
    CustomerNumber = cc.CustomerNumber             
    }
    )
```

[entities shown in VS Model Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Mqy.png)

Comment: You have to follow a course or a tutorial, if you haven't start coding yet. If you have written any code, show us how far you got. Remember : we are not here to code for you, but to solve SPECIFIC problems. You went through to help page ? Well... for now your question is too broad, but you can make it better

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I will update with my current query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the `HasCard` from `CustomerLockers` by filtering on `LockerNumber`;

```
CustomerLockers = cc.Customer.CustomerLockers
```

The query;

```
var myCustomers = (from cc in context.ContractCustomers
    where cc.Contract_ID.Equals(contractID)
    select new
    {
        Licencee = cc.IsLicencee,
        Added = cc.AddedDate,
        Firstname = cc.Customer.FirstName,
        Lastname = cc.Customer.LastName,
        DOB = cc.Customer.DateOfBirth,
        Postcode = cc.Customer.PostCode,
        CustomerNumber = cc.CustomerNumber,
        CustomerLockerHasCard = cc.Customer.CustomerLockers
                        .Where(x => x.LockerNumber == 1000)
                        .Select(x => x.HasCard)
    }
)
```

Also, I suggest you to define model classes as known type instead of using anonymous type.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  How can I select specific properties from the CustomerLocker entity (e.g. HasCard) where the LockerNumber is 1000?

Comment: @Samuel ... That's another question, we can't accompany you and build your project together. That comment may be candidat for another question. Rembeber, one question at a time.

Comment: Dear Antione Pelletier - this is notanother question as it is exactly what I asked in my original question - "related properties from the CustomerLocker and ContractCustomer entities".

Comment: Dear Stormcloak - your answer is exactly what I required. Thank you kindly for your excellent assistance.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to get the list of customers instead of just the customer's number :

```
var myCustomers = (from cc in context.ContractCustomers
where cc.Contract_ID.Equals(contractID)
select new
{
    Licencee = cc.IsLicencee,
    Added = cc.AddedDate,
    Firstname = cc.Customer.FirstName,
    Lastname = cc.Customer.LastName,
    DOB = cc.Customer.DateOfBirth,
    Postcode = cc.Customer.PostCode,
    CustomerNumber = cc.CustomerNumber,
    listOfCustomers = cc.Customer.ToList() // <-Here, a list
}
)
```

Then you can use a loop :

```
foreach(var customer in myCustomers.listOfCustomers)
{
    var listOfLockers = customer.CustomerLockers.ToList();
}
```

But this is more a beginner's way, remember it's always better to take everything you need in a single query, like Stormcloack's answer.

This answer is just to show you how you can dig in the entitys the easy way.

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance.  I am familiar with the option you have shown but I would like to use a more efficient query.